# ResourceEditor LWUIT NoClassDefFoundError: com/app/XMLMidlet: com/sun/lwuit/events/ActionListener

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I have developed  Rss App LWUIT Project using ResourceEditor.

I opened the project in Netbeans IDE, I followed the link at developers Nokia site *Generating the NetBeans project in the Resource Editor* - [Adding GUI resource file manually into your project](https://projects.developer.nokia.com/LWUIT_for_Series_40/wiki/UsingTheResourceEditorToGenerateAproject#BAddingGUIresourcefilemanuallyintoyourproject).

While running my application, I am facing Uncaught exception

```
 java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: com/app/XMLMidlet: com/sun/lwuit/events/ActionListener
```

Could I do any extra thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy the res file to your package folder,
then,

```
Display.init(this);  
    try {
        Resources r = Resources.open("/resource.res");

        UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme(
            r.getThemeResourceNames()[0])
        );
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    }
```